# missing key element in applescript, don't know enough to fix

Tags: macos, applescript, osx-mountain-lion, automator

I am using applescript in automator to download backups of websites using sitesucker.
The original method wasnt working, so i contacted the creator of sitesucker. turns out there was a problem with that feature in the current version so he gives me an applescript to do do the same thing.
Problem: I know basically nothing about applescript and dont understand how to specify the URLs i need downloaded.

here is the script i was given:

```
    on run {input, parameters}

    tell application "SiteSucker"
        activate

        -- Create a new document
        set front_document to make new document

        -- Get the download folder
        tell settings of front_document
            set download_folder to download folder as alias
            set download_folder_path to POSIX path of download_folder
        end tell

        -- Download the specified URLs
        repeat with the_url in input
            download the_url
        end repeat

        -- Wait until the download is finished before continuing
        repeat while downloading of front_document
            delay 1
        end repeat

    end tell

    return download_folder_path

end run
```

I tried contacting the person who gave me the script, But they have not responded. I thought maybe i could get a faster answer on these forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to play with the applescript they gave you.

Place the script into a new  'Run Applescript' Action (overwrite the default contents)

And add a 'Get Specified URLS' Automator Action above it.

Add you Urls to the 'Get Specified URLS' Automator Action.

[image]

Comment: I think that this is a smart answer.